# How to create a toogle button to show and clear output using ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to create a toggle button to display some output and clear it when switched in jupyter notebook using `ipywidget`.

I tried to do it using `widgets.Output()`. This however displays empty lines as I click more and more times.

Please help me out.

```py
import ipywidgets as w
toggle = w.ToggleButton(description='click me')

out = w.Output()

def fun(obj):
    global out
    with out:
        display('asd')
    if obj['new']:  
        display(out)
    else:
        out.clear_output()
        out = w.Output()

toggle.observe(fun, 'value')
display(toggle)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the combination of `global` keyword with the `display(out)` is causing the issue here. I've simplified a little bit below:

Display the `output` widget in the main body of your code, and use the `clear_output` command (the output widget is still 'visible' but is zero height).

```py
    import ipywidgets as w
    toggle = w.ToggleButton(description='click me')

    out = w.Output(layout=w.Layout(border = '1px solid black'))

    def fun(obj):
        with out:
            if obj['new']:  
                display('asd')
            else:
                out.clear_output()

    toggle.observe(fun, 'value')
    display(toggle)
    display(out)
```

Comment: (the output widget is still 'visible' but is zero height)
Could you please explain this to me? Although it's working fine, I just want to know what exactly did you mean by it? Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: See my edited version with a border to illustrate what happens to the output widget.